# Why is rev() slower than indexing in the opposite order?

Tags: r, optimization

I wonder why `rev` is 10 times slower than indexing in the reverse order.

```
> a <- rnorm(100)
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a[length(a):1], rev(a))
Unit: microseconds
           expr    min      lq     mean median     uq     max neval cld
 a[length(a):1]  1.590  1.7620  1.98496  1.968  2.099   3.708   100  a 
         rev(a) 10.885 11.6075 14.46583 11.860 12.126 176.827   100   b
```

Are there situations where `rev` is the best solution ?

*Edit: avoiding S3 dispatch almost entirely removes the speed difference.*

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a[length(a):1], rev(a), rev.default(a))
Unit: microseconds
           expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
 a[length(a):1]  1.764  1.9970  2.26030  2.2065  2.4115   4.112   100  a 
         rev(a) 11.325 12.1815 14.07172 12.4890 12.9110 128.009   100   b
 rev.default(a)  2.155  2.5205  2.87756  2.6870  2.8565  22.553   100  a
```

*Edit 2: actually, the dispatch overhead is negligible on large vectors*

```
> a <- rnorm(1e6)
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a[length(a):1], rev(a), rev.default(a))
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval cld
 a[length(a):1] 6.572286 7.044723 25.73596 8.401815  9.443036 263.6888   100   a
         rev(a) 6.655199 8.189631 40.73245 8.647586 10.015620 262.7886   100   a
 rev.default(a) 6.531415 8.203819 28.39852 8.495920  9.755701 268.0045   100   a
```

Comment: rev is an S3 generic that needs to check the input type. did you try with `rev.default` ? that will probably be a fraction slower as well since there is also a conditional

Comment: I also can't replicate this huge difference. I get only about 3x slower, as opposed to the >7x shown here. Using `rev.default` as @rawr suggetss brings the difference down to only about 19% slower (1.19x).

Comment: and FWIW, even the R-Doc is pretty down on rev() these days: " this is no longer needed (nor efficient) for obtaining vectors sorted into descending order, since that is now rather more directly achievable by sort."

Comment: @Peter_Evan - that highlights the efficiency of `sort` and it's `decreasing=TRUE` argument, but I'm not sure how it is being down on `rev`. Sorting in reverse order of magnitude isn't the same as reversing. I suspect, looking at the examples section that the old way of sorting descending in R was to do `rev(sort(x))` before `sort` was improved.

Comment: The overhead of the conditional in `rev.default` is also not proportional. Consider larger `a`'s. Try with `a <- rnorm(1e6)` and the difference is still only `0.00063` seconds.

Comment: If this difference of a few microseconds really matters to you, you should optimize your code more fundamentally.